# What does next Badge and Impact mean in new Profile page?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

The new Stack Overflow profile page looks nice and it's cool, but I want to know what "Next badge" and "Impact" mean.

[image: New profile page]

Comment: Hover over the `Impact` label and click the gear next to the `Next Badge` to see more.

Comment: @BrianTracy Ok i got info on `Impact` but nothing to display in `Next Badge`.

Comment: @M D, It shows you how close you are to a specific badge. You even change the badge in question.

Comment: Hi there I've got a question after lookin at your profile pic! what is that `105` on top menubar just before **review** link?

Comment: @Vikrant It's an `Number of Review Post`.

Comment: Oh, but @MD, why I m not able to see it on my profile then? though i m reviewing `Triage, First and Late posts`

Comment: @Vikrant For that you need `>=10k` rep.

Comment: @MD , Not really.I don't have 10K rep yet and I can still see the number(sometimes). I can see the number of suggested edits there. So I think that one needs 3K rep to see it.

Comment: @CoolGuy I don't remember but some `moderator` told me this. So i guess it's was.

Comment: This was asked several times on meta.stackexchange.com - for example [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/202747).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Next Badge**

To track the progress towards the next possible badge. For details (or to change the tracker), click on the wheel next to it and it will expand like

[image]

where you can see the break-down for the progress as well as change the tracker.

**Impact**

It's precisely your presence in the site (edits, votes, flags included, as you can see) and the effects of your contribution. Hover over the IMPACT to see the details regarding this

[image]