# Does 'Next Badge' feature improve the quality of content on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, quality-improvement, badge-progress

New user page is great - clear, readable and useful. It also introduces new feature - 'Next Badge', that some users [were already asking about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290393/what-does-next-badge-and-impact-in-new-profile-page). However, I am concerned, whether this feature is not a step into wrong direction.

Stack Overflow already faces a lot of problems - even if there are many responsible users, hard-working moderators and people, who simply want to help, we can constantly observe decreasing level of quality of content - both questions and answers. Not to mention spam, multiple edits, that don't improve anything (even more, they often drastically change the original question or break author's intentions) and so on.

Now, when we got such feature, won't this force some users to focus on achievements, instead of help in building better Stack Overflow?

Yes, there are audits, yes, edits of new users are peer-reviewed and yes - SO is built with trust and cooperation in mind. But still, should we demand more such features? Not everything, that looks nice and is useful for individuals is beneficial to the community as a whole.

What is your opinion?

Comment: Badges are intended to encourage productive behavior.  Granted, there will also be people trying to game the system with half-baked work, but prompting users to take productive actions (like answering, editing, and reviewing) will improve SO as a consequence (IMO).

Comment: It's also worth noting that people have asked for a badge progress meter that they can easily get to and look at. This was probably the teams attempt to answer that. True, it could _potentially_ encourage gaming behavior, but at the same time, so does having badges in the first place (to a lesser degree). Overall, this is a very good question and might be worth looking into, if it wouldn't be too hard to study the effects of the badge tracker.

Comment: I dunno, I think badges should just happen organically, instead of saying "You're 495 reviews away from a shiny new badge!"  For reviews, for example, it would be nice if the progress bar area instead showed "You have X amount of rep, did you know you can Review?" with a link to a Meta post on how to review, and a link to the review queue itself.  Nudge people to improve the site, without gaming the system.  Are people who are *that* interested in when they get their next badge really that interested in improving the site, or just getting the reward?

Comment: `Does it improve the quality?` No. How could it? `Does it reduce it?` Probably not. The lack of quality generally doesn't come from people who care about *anything* on the site.

Comment: Is this really more of a problem than having a link to all of the badges at the top of every single page? I just don't see how someone focusing on getting badges can do so in a way that hurts the community. Who cares if someone decides to get the Citizen Patrol badges? If the flags are helpful, then they were good for the SO community, right?

Answer (score 3):

> Now, when we got such feature, won't this force some users to focus on achievements, instead of help in building better Stack Overflow?

I would say **No not really**. As first point, I'd like to say that the people who actually go for 'Achievements', do care about Stack Overflow (or at least about their name on Stack Overflow). Otherwise they wouldn't spend the time to go for the achievements. So most people won't just post bad quality for the sake of the achievements if it can damage their name/reputation.

Secondly, almost all of the badges are only obtainable by either being reviewed by someone first (*edit badges*) or well received by the community (*question and answer badges*). The only badges I can think of that people would go for without providing good quality are:

- Vote badges
- Commentator and Pundit badge
- Tumbleweed

And maybe even getting good quality indirect through the badge process of  **Enthusiast**(*Visited the site each day for 30 consecutive days.*) of a user.

Now just to clarify, I'd say that there **might** be a little bit of quality loss but I don't think it would happen.

Comment: Well, in fact, my main concern was review badges - especially `Triage` and `Suggested Edits`, where low quality posts and trivial edits are often approved, while they should be flagged/rejected.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek I've also thought about the review badges, but to me it doesn't necessarily mean that the amount of low quality posts will rise. People do it anyway even without the badge process on their profile.